# The same apache mod_rewrite config works on one machine, fails on another

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

httpd.conf(at home computer):

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

....

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
</Directory>

<Directory "Z:/www_data">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

</Directory>
```

.htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php [L]
```

go to url `localhost/cabinet/add_resume`
404 not found (at home computer)

At work computer it works,

At home, no.

Comment: .htaccess at work computer === .htaccess at home computer.

Comment: `AllowOverride All`? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#allowoverride

Comment: Try `AllowOverride all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
AllowOverride None
```

This directive plainly disables the use of .htaccess files altogether.
Please set it to something more useful, like:

```
AllowOverride All
```